# Create new Azure DevOps Pipeline when release branch created

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am investigating Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 as a replacement for our Bamboo Server that has just gone End Of Life.

We create a version number is based on the branch name e.g. release/4.214.0 and we add the sequential build number of the build to create our release version e.g. 4.214.0.5

At the moment we have a Release build plan to checkout code, set a build number in a file, build and then create versioned nuget packages for deployment.

We use Bamboo Branch rules to create a plan branch for each release branch so we reset the build number for each release branch we create and have different entries on our build radiator as 4.214.0, 4.215.0, 4.216.0 etc are seen as different plans and we can have 4.214.0.1, 4.215.0.1, 4.216.0.1 etc

I have an Azure Pipeline that does all the steps I need (create version number, build, package etc.) but when I run it against different branches I get the next sequential build number so I would get 4.214.0.1, 4.215.0.2, 4.216.0.3 etc and I wouldn't be able to have 4.215.0.2.

The only way I can see round this is to manually create a copy of the pipeline every time a new release branch is created.

Is there some plan branch equivalent in Azure DevOps that I am overlooking or some other way round this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`counter` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops). You feed it a prefix and a seed -- so `counter(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 0)` would create a counter based on the branch name that starts at 0.

Note that this should be used as a runtime expression, not a compile time expression, so wrapped in `$[]`, not `${{}}`.